# Does optimizer highly affect on accuracy?

Tags: deep-learning, optimization

I used SGD as optimizer and its accuracy result is about 97%

[image: sgd]

and I have changed optimizer to Adam

surprisingly, my accuracy became 49%

I only changed optimizer and didn`t change anything else

but the result became very different

[image: adam]

is it normal?

Does optimizer highly affect on accuracy?

Comment: What method/package do you use: Keras? What type of task: binary classification? Did you run the script again? It should not be the case that "no learning" takes place just because you switch the optimizer.

Comment: I used Keras for multiclass classification and did run the script twice.

Comment: Changing the optimizer doesn't change the function you want to optimise, so the results shouldn't be different unless there is a problem on your way to an optimum. Given your graphs a wild guess is that when changing the optimizer you also changed default option like early stopping conditions. Thats why Adam stoped before reaching a better optimum (and thus a better accuracy).